# How to find a potential of a differential form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I need some help in understanding the meaning of this exercise:

Determine a potential of the following differential form

$$\omega = (3x^2y + z) dx + (x^3 + 2yz) dy + (y^2 + x) dz$$

I don't understand exactly the command.

Comment: I think it wants you to find a differential form $\eta$ such that $d \eta = \omega$.  The term "potential form" is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms).

Comment: @littleO That could be.. Great hint! I'll do the math now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine a function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega = df$

Comment: Understood!! It was the term "potential" that tricked me. Now the exercises is like done. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)